Did Microsoft/Office 365 break the EWS multi-folder FindItem
Our apps have used multi-folder FindItem method feature of EWS for years and since a few days ago we see an increasing number of failures of this EWS functionality. The Office 365 servers return results for less folders than requested.
<m:FindItem Traversal≈"Shallow">...multiple folders: <t:FolderId Id≈"">...<t:FolderId Id≈"">...


microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The service was expected to return FindItemResponseMessage response of type '18', but 10 response were received.

This looks like a recent breaking update by Microsoft that is gradually propagating to more tenants as we see these failures for more and more users every day.
Has anyone encountered this yet?
What would you say is a good channel to bring this to Microsoft's attention?
Thank you

Looks like they have found and have started to remediated it https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/servicehealth/:/alerts/EX921969

Thank you. We see that they have fixed it.
